# "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz" string convert to Date

Tags: swift, string, date, extension-methods

Dears, help to convert string as "Mon, 10 Apr 2017, 10:00:00 PDT" to Date
My code below, unfortunately it causes error:

```
extension String {    
    func getDate() -> Date {
       let formatter = DateFormatter()

       formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz"
       return formatter.date(from: self)! // Returns "Mon, 10 Apr 2017, 10:00:00 PDT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. You need to add a comma after the year and use HH (24 hour) instead of hh (12 hour) in your dateFormat:

```
extension Formatter {
    static let date = DateFormatter()
}

extension String {
    var getDate: Date? {
        Formatter.date.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        Formatter.date.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss zzz"
        return Formatter.date.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

---

```
let dateString =  "Mon, 10 Apr 2017, 10:00:00 PDT"
if let date = dateString.getDate {
    Formatter.date.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "PDT")
    Formatter.date.string(from: date)  // Mon, 10 Apr 2017, 10:00:00 PDT
}
```